# Locating a button by xpath or id

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The website source is:

```
<iframe id="fast-checkout-iframe">
<div  class="celwidget" >
        <span class="a" data-action="place-order">
           <span id="checkout-place-order-button" >
             <span class="a-button-inner">
               <input id="fast-checkout-button" type="submit" value="Place your order" >
                 <span id="fast-checkout-place-order-button-announce" >Place your order
</span></span></span></span></div>
</iframe>
```

I'm trying to click to switch to the iframe and click the button.

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
self.driver.find_element_by_id("fast-checkout-button").click()
```

But I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="fast-checkout-button"]"}
```

```
What should I do? Thanks!
```

Comment: Your element must be inside `iframe`?? Please check DOM tree if you have any parent element  like `iframe` above the element you have posted? If not try with explicit wait.

Comment: Yes. I see an iframe tag above...what can I do?

Comment: Is there only 1 iframe on the page? I believe you can swith_to using the id

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following xpath.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
buttons = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='fast-checkout-button']")))
buttons.click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you still getting timeout error then please check it is under `iframe` or not

---

**Update**.

you need to switch to `iframe` first in order to access the element inside iframe.

```
#Switch to frame
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "fast-checkout-iframe")))  
#Click on the button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, //input[@id='fast-checkout-button']"))).click()

#To switch back to the main
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I see the iframe ..I forget to check for this. Any idea what I can do? Using your solution I get timeout error..

Comment: @MMarie : You need to switch the iframe first ? can please post the html of the iframe?

Comment: I changed the initial post:)

Answer (score 0):

As @KunduK mentions, it would be best to wait for your elements.  In addition, just looking at the source, I think that you should be attempting to click on the `input` element, not the `span`.  so use the id `fast-checkout-button` instead.